# Vuforia DataSet exists but fails to load on iOS devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I made an AR app using the Vuforia SDK in Unity. Everything works fine when deployed to Android. when I deploy to iOS devices, like the iPhone 5s, the DataSet with my marker exists, but fails to load and activate.

```
dataSetExists
Dataset _______ could not be loaded and cannot be activated.
```

I've been searching the Vuforia forums (i.e. this: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/dataset-exists-fails-load-and-activate), but nothing helped. I have a proper path, I built the project on a Mac, I don't miss the PostProcessBuildPlayer script in my project.

I did have problems building the app in XCode tho. I used the advice found here (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/linker-error-on-xcode6-1-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-unitykeyboard_gettext.309464/), in Redons last reply, to solve the problem - I manually re-added needed libraries to the XCode project and added Security.framework in "Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries". Is this relevant?

I'm working on Unity 5.2.1 and XCode 6.3

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does it work in Editor (platform set to iOS) ?

Comment: @peterept I don't have a web cam compatibile with my Mac Mini, but I can buy one if it is necessary.

Comment: It makes Vuforia development a lot faster and easier having a webcam in the editor - and you'd see any dataset errors right there.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was that I manually added the following compiler directive to the ARCamera's LoadDatabaseBehaviour script under the AddOSSpecificExternalDatasetSearchDirs function:

```
#if UNITY_IOS

    AddExternalDatasetSearchDir(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/QCAR/");

#endif
```

This is an iOS specific fix that explicitly points to the Streaming Assets folder in the iOS build itself.

My versions & info:

- Unity version: 5.3.0f4
- Vuforia version: 5.0.6
- OSX version: 10.11.2 (El Capitan)
- Xcode version: 7.2 (7C68)
- iOS device: iPad mini 3
- iOS version: 9.1

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. In our project we are currently using vuforia 9.8.8 can you pl. let us know where need to go and change the path of the data set.